# how can I do something on new user registration?

Tags: plugins, php, themes

When I register a new user to my blog, I always receive an email. The code in simple terms should look like this.

```
on_new_user_registration(){

        //send email to admin
        //I want to do something else.

  }
```

I would like to do more than receiving an email. Can someone point me to the right code.

I have tried using the `wp_insert_user()` function in wordpress but that creates the user inside the editor.

thanks a lot.

Comment: ***What*** more would  you like to do?

Comment: create a directory with the new user's username where I can store his/her images on a plugin that I am working on

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You want to use the [`user_register`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference/user_register) hook, probably. Then use the [Filesystem API](http://codex.wordpress.org/Filesystem_API) to make the folder. Be aware that filesystem manipulation is dependent upon server configuration and may not always work, but using the API should ameliorate that problem as much as possible.

Comment: I think a simple code example could help.